# How to remove string None from a single string with commas and count the most common words in a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-re

I have rows in a df formed by a string that contains several elements separated by commas.

Among the rows, there are words of interest (eg. Car, Bus) and the word None. Also, there are rows that only have the word None.

Here is an example of df:

| Col |
| --- |
| Car, None, None, Car, Bus, None |
| None |
| Bus, Bus, None, Car, Car, None |
| None, None, None |

Here is an example of the expected result:

| Col | Most common words |
| --- | --- |
| Car, Car, Bus | Car (2) |
| Bus, Bus, Car, Car | Bus (2), Car (2) |

In short: I need to remove None from the rows with the words of interest; delete rows consisting only of None and finally I need to count the words of interest remaining in the rows?

Is there any way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the "Col" column with `.str.split(", ")`, filter out the `None` values, empty lists and count unique items with `.value_counts()`:

```py
df.Col = df.Col.str.split(", ").apply(lambda x: [v for v in x if v != "None"])
df = df[df.Col.str.len() > 0]

df["Most common words"] = df.Col.apply(
    lambda x: ", ".join(
        f"{a} ({b})" for a, b in pd.Series(x).value_counts().to_dict().items()
    )
)
df.Col = df.Col.apply(", ".join)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                  Col Most common words
0       Car, Car, Bus  Car (2), Bus (1)
2  Bus, Bus, Car, Car  Bus (2), Car (2)
```

---

`df` used:

```py
                               Col
0  Car, None, None, Car, Bus, None
1                             None
2   Bus, Bus, None, Car, Car, None
3                 None, None, None
```

Comment: Did you do anything else to your code? I copied what you did and applied it to another df, but something went wrong, because now I have something like Car (None), bus (None)...

Comment: @PSCM No, the exact same code (I've added used dataframe). (Note: The values of column `Col` are of type string, not lists).

Comment: That's weird. I checked and the error occurs on this line: **.str.split(", ").apply(lambda x: [v for v in x if v != "None"])**. For some reason, the word None is not removed from the set.

Comment: @PSCM Maybe there's some whitespace(s)? Try `.str.split(", ").apply(lambda x: [v for v in map(str.strip, x) if v != "None"])`